# Bitwise XOR ends in SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, xor, bitwise-xor

I have a function which shall perform simple Bitwise-XOR encryption. It looks like this:

```
void maskData(char* data, int length)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                int j = i % 4;
                cout << bitset<8>(data[i]) << endl << bitset<8>(this->maskingKey[j]) << endl;
                data[i] ^= this->maskingKey[j];
            }
        }
```

The output of the application is:

```
01010100
01001011
```

Then it dies. I attached `gdb` to it and found out that an SIGSEGV-Exception is raised.

```
01010100
01001011

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004100ea in WebSocketLayer::WebSocketFrame::maskData (
    this=0x7fffffffe190, data=0x423621 "This is a test", length=14)
    at ../BoostTransport/WebSocketLayer.h:130
130                 data[i] ^= this->maskingKey[j];
```

I am really not sure why this is happening, everything seems OK to me.

**Edit:** More Code:

```
    void setData(char* data, int length)
    {
                this->maskData(data, length);

     // ... ...
     }

wf.setData("This is a test", strlen("This is a test"));
```

The loop directly fails in the first run, which means `i` and `j` are 0.

Comment: What value is `i`? What value is `j`? What value is `this`? Are `i` and `j` within range? Does `data` point to a constant? Show us the code that calls `maskData`.

Comment: can you add the calling code as well?  It looks like you're passing in "This is a test" and length 14 - but just so we can see how you're calling it.

Comment: Since C++11 you should get a compilation error for the attempt to point non-const `char *` at an array of `const char`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet `data` points to a constant. You can't modify a constant, that's what makes them constants. So anything comparable to `maskData("hello", 5);` is illegal. This is also illegal:

```
char *j = "This is a test";
maskData(j, strlen(j));
```

Here, `j` points to a constant. You can't modify a constant.

Comment: How can I do it then?

Comment: `char j[] = "This is a test";`

Comment: Based on the value of `data=0x423621`, that virtual memory address (being around 4MB from 0) is almost certainly program read-only memory. Heap addresses tend to be bigger, and stack addresses start with 0x7FFFFF.... (`this` for example).  I think David is right.

Comment: Start by only storing pointers to constants in `const`-qualified pointers. And see if you can get your compiler to give you a warning if you do otherwise.

Comment: Rewrite `setData` to take a `const char *` parameter. We'd have to see the rest of the function to know how to rewrite it properly. (For example, if you modify the data and then copy it, change the order to copy before modifying.) Or maybe take `std::string`?

Comment: I think `const char *` to `char *` conversion should produce a error by default and only allowed by special compilation option, not the vice versa.

Comment: @Slava that'd be nice..unfortunately it seems compiler developers have other priorities